# Script changed from Standalone to Bound. Sheets now shows .length undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, typeerror

I have a working standalone script that gets values from a Google Sheet and created docs from a template file. I copied it into a bound script in a new Google Sheet. The only changes I made was to change the reference from a set document to the active document/sheet.  It now throws the error 'TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined.'

I've logged the variable and it gives me values, so I know it can't an empty variable. I've gone back and tracked permissions and made sure I had the right APIs turned on.

I imagine it has to be somehow in how the bound scripts work, but I can't find the difference in the documentation.

Original (working) Code

```
function createDocument() {
 var headers = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('17jXy9IlLt8C41tWEG5iQR31GjzOftlJs73y2L_0ZWNM', 'A1:Q1');
 var tactics = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('17jXy9IlLt8C41tWEG5iQR31GjzOftlJs73y2L_0ZWNM', 'A2:Q');
 var templateId = '16SqhR3pxm7Pk6LqSWeONFP84bYxty7g2cXcTp15qjYY';

for(var i = 0; i < tactics.values.length; i++){    
  var customer = tactics.values[i][0];
```

Copied to Bound Script Code (throws error)

```
function createDocument() {
  var headers = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Report').getRange('A1:Q1').getValues();
  var tactics = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Report').getRange('A2:Q').getValues();
  var templateId = '16SqhR3pxm7Pk6LqSWeONFP84bYxty7g2cXcTp15qjYY';
  Logger.log(tactics)

  for(var i = 0; i < tactics.values.length; i++){    
    var customer = tactics.values[i][0];
```

I'm expecting the code I've added to the script in the Google sheet to generate reports the same as the standalone script. Instead I get 'TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined.'

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
    tactics.values.length
```

by

```
 tactics.length
```

and

```
var customer = tactics.values[i][0];
```

by

```
var customer = tactics[i][0];
```

Comment: That solves the .length undefined issue, but now the loop doesn't come to a natural stop, it will only stop once it hit either the end of the range...or the bottom of the spreadsheet 150 lines (and documents) later.

When I limit it to two rows, it is showing me the values I expect, but then the second line is an empty set : [, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ]]

Comment: @Stephen That's because you are using an open reference than belongs to a sheet that has empty rows. Instead of the open reference you could use getLastRow method from Class Sheet to find the last row, among other alternativas. Of you need further help post a mes question including a [mcve]

Comment: I went back to my original code, and instead of using the second example to identify the spreadsheet and range, I went back to the first and put the range as 'Autofill!A1:Q1' That let me have it get the active spreadsheet (which I wanted) fill in the sheet I needed it to pull from (which I needed) and have it self limit to only rows with data.  That seems to work now.